# Properties and Outliner visibility

Tags: properties, outliner

Properties and outliner not showing at the same time in the layout tab. How do I have them both visible at the same time?  I can only see one or the other.

[image: with properties enabled]

Answer (score 1):

1. Move the mouse to the border between the 3D view and properties.
2. Right click and select *Split area*
3. Position the split
4. Select the outliner from the dropdown for the newly created window area.

Comment: Thanks. I feel like an idiot.  looks like the window was slid way down and all I had to do was click and drag.  Apologies, and the thanks for the help. Worked your way as well.